# Create a sequence of minutes from midnight to midnight in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am plotting times of day with R. Here is my code:

```
library(chron)
t <- times(c("00:13:00", "00:30:00", "00:34:00", "00:36:00", "00:45:00", "00:48:00", "01:08:00", "01:14:00", "01:15:00", "01:25:00", "02:06:00", "02:07:00", "02:22:00", "02:23:00", "02:36:00", "02:37:00", "02:55:00", "03:08:00", "03:10:00", "03:11:00", "03:13:00", "03:15:00", "03:23:00", "03:35:00", "03:45:00", "03:55:00", "03:57:00", "03:58:00", "04:03:00", "04:06:00", "04:15:00", "04:21:00", "04:21:00", "04:22:00", "04:34:00", "04:43:00", "04:48:00", "04:51:00", "04:54:00", "04:58:00", "05:00:00", "05:02:00", "05:03:00", "05:17:00", "05:25:00", "05:34:00", "05:38:00", "05:45:00", "05:46:00", "05:50:00", "05:52:00", "06:10:00", "06:11:00", "06:13:00", "06:23:00", "06:26:00", "22:18:00", "23:27:00", "23:40:00", "23:53:00", "23:54:00", "23:58:00"))
hist(as.numeric(t), breaks = "Freedman-Diaconis", probability = TRUE, col = "gray", ylim = c(0, 10), xlab = "Time", ylab = "Density", main = "Times")
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: xxx]

Now, instead of Freedman-Diaconis, **I'd like the bins to be exactly one minute wide**.

But for one, I cannot create a time series that spans the whole day (from midnight to midnight), because the largest full minute time I can input for `to` is 23:59:00, so my sequence misses the last bin that would include times between 23:59:00 and midnight:

```
seq(from = times("00:00:00"), to = times("23:59:00"), by = times("00:00:01"))
```

Also, using this sequence as breaks in `hist()` throws an error (with or without casting the times `as.numeric()`):

```
Error in hist.default(as.numeric(t), breaks = as.numeric(seq(times("00:00:00"),  : 
  some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
```

## How can I create one minute wide breaks from midnight to midnight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was:

```
breaks = seq(times(0), times(1), by = times("00:01:00"))
```

That is, I defined the times numerically, with `times(1)` being one full day.

It looks like this:

[image]